# What does it mean for a moment generating function to exist in a neighborhood of 0?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, moment-generating-function

It is my understanding that a moment generating function (MGF) uniquely determines a distribution with bounded or unbounded support only if the "MGF exists in a neighborhood of zero."  But what does it mean exactly for an MGF to exist in a neighborhood of zero?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding to Bey's answer, there's a reason you might care about this. The idea is that the MGF is a Laplace transform, and in this case it requires that your (continuous) probability density $f(x)$ decreases at least exponentially fast for large $x$, i.e. $e^{tx}f(x)\rightarrow 0$ for $x\rightarrow\infty$. This can be somewhat weakened but the main idea survives.

Anyways, it's usually the case that if $t$ is too large, this becomes false. So for example if $f(x)=2e^{-2x}$, then the MGF exists (i.e. is finite), for $t\in[0,2)$. As long as $f(t)$ is a density, everything is fine for $t<0$ but it turns out $t>0$ contains a wealth more of information.  In general, saying that the MGF exists in a neighborhood of $0$ means that there is some $\epsilon>0$ such that your MGF is finite for all $t\in[0,\epsilon)$. Once your MGF exists, by abstract nonsense it corresponds to a unique distribution (your $f(x)$) and you can exploit all of it's nice properties, for example use it to [bound probabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_lemma). In similar vein to characteristic functions (i.e. fourier transforms), the regularity of your MGF near $t=0$ is intimately connected to the rate of decay of your density $f(x)$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$, an example of which you can see in the last link.

Perhaps more familiar to you, derivatives of the MGF, evaluated at $t=0$ give you back the moments of your distribution, so perhaps you can believe why you really only need to know what your $MGF$ looks likes near $t=0$ to extract almost everything about your random variable.

Answer (score 6):

The MGF of a random variable $X$ is given by:

$$\mathrm{MGF}_X = \mathbb{E}[e^{tX}]$$

Where it is a function of $t$.

As you can see, the MGF at $t=0$ is always $1$, even if $X$ is, say, a Cauchy random variable, which has no moments. So, basically, when mathematicians say "a neighborhood", they mean:

$$\exists \epsilon>0: \forall t \in (-\epsilon,\epsilon),\;\;\mathbb{E}[e^{tX}]< \infty$$

Note, it just needs to be *some* positive constant.

Answer (score 3):

I thought I'd chime in with an example that illustrates when we might have to worry about this.

Suppose $X \sim Exp(\lambda)$ so that the probability density function is:
$$f(x\vert \lambda) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}$$

Then the moment generating function is:
$$M_X(t) = E(e^{Xt}) = \int_0^\infty e^{xt} \lambda e^{-\lambda x} dx = \lambda \int_0^\infty e^{x(t - \lambda)}dx$$

Notice that if $t - \lambda \geq 0$, then this integral diverges. 
$$M_X(t) = \lambda\int_0^\infty e^{x(t - \lambda)}dx = \begin{cases}
\infty, & t \geq \lambda \\
\frac{\lambda}{\lambda - t}, & t < \lambda
\end{cases}$$

In otherwords, $M_X(t)$ is finite only when $t < \lambda$. But since $\lambda$ is strictly positive, there exists a neighborhood $N_\lambda(0)$ for which the MGF exists and we can use it in the usual way.